# Use mysqlimport with a subset of a file's columns

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, mysqlimport

I have a file, say `data.csv`, which is coming into my server, and which I want to import to the `data` table in a MySQL database using `mysqlimport`.

My issue is, this file has a lot more data than I actually want to import. It is used by another server before me which needs all this data, but I only need a handful of columns from it.

*Is there a way to specify what columns I want `mysqlimport` to use?*

I thought it would look something like

```
mysqlimport --columns="field_1","field_2","field_42","field_31","field_16","field_4" db data.csv
```

but the table just contains the first 6 fields of the file instead. If needs be, I can rearrange the table so that the fields I want are in order (i.e., I'd be running `--columns="field_1","field_2","field_4","field_16",...`).

I'm vaguely aware that this could be done using `sed`, but I'm curious whether `mysqlimport` natively supports it?

**EDIT:** The accepted answer isn't exactly what I was hoping for, but I think the answer is, "no, it sadly doesn't support it". In any case, check out the accepted answer and comments for workarounds!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `--columns` option doesn't name the columns of the input file. It names the columns of the destination table you are importing into. All the fields of the input file need to go somewhere. You need to have as many columns in `--columns` as the fields of the input file.

But not all the fields of the input file need to go into columns of your table.

Huh?

Here's a trick (this works in `LOAD DATA INFILE` too): You can "send" the fields of the input to either a real column of your table, or to a session variable. This variable will just get overwritten by every row input from your file, but that doesn't matter. Think of it like a dummy variable in a code project.

Example: I created a table with three columns.

```
mysql> create table mytable (one text, two text, four text);
```

I created an input text file with four fields.

```
$ cat mytable.csv
one,two,three,four
```

Here I import the fields into their respective columns, skipping field three by putting it into a dummy variable.

```
$ mysqlimport --local --columns one,two,@dummy,four --fields-terminated-by=, test mytable.csv
```

Success!

```
mysql> select * from mytable;
+------+------+------+
| one  | two  | four |
+------+------+------+
| one  | two  | four |
+------+------+------+
```

Comment: Interesting, that could certainly be useful, but the input has 52 columns, so it would look very inelegant to have ~45 of the columns say `@dummy`... Is there a way to, say, send multiple columns from the input into this `@dummy` variable? Like `--columns one,two,@dummy*7,ten`

Comment: You would have to use `one,two,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,ten`. If you don't like that, then prepare an input file that has the right columns. Sed is not the best tool for this, I would use `cut`.

Comment: It should be clear that there is nothing special about the variable name `@dummy`. You could use `@d` or anything else you want.

Comment: Thanks for those all those tips! Yes, I think the best thing might be to just bite the bullet and prepare another file. As a matter of interest, why `cut` over `sed`? Is it faster?

Comment: You don't have to write regular expressions if you use `cut`. For example to print comma-separated fields 1,2,10: `cut -d, -f1,2,10` Read `man cut` for more information.

Comment: Ah, little bit simpler, gotcha. `cut` does (sadly) have trouble working with csv files whose fields have commas in them, even if those fields are enclosed in quotes. Doesn't seem like there's anyway to get it to ignore a comma enclosed in quotes.

Comment: Okay in that case I'd go with python's `csv` module. It's very configurable. Read https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: But if you have fields with commas embedded, you're going to have a bad day trying to parse it with `sed`. :-(

Comment: Yeah, but at least `sed` let me convert it to a tab-delimited input, which I could then use `cut` on!